# Kubernetes pod distribution

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I've worked quite a lot with Docker in the past years, but I'm a newbie when it comes to Kubernetes. I'm starting today and I am struggling with the usefulness of the Pod concept in comparison with the way I used to do thinks with Docker swarm.

Let's say that I have a cluster with 7 powerful machines and I have the following stack:

- I want three Cassandra replicas each running in a dedicated machine (3/7)
- I want two Kafka replicas each running in a dedicated machine (5/7)
- I want a MyProducer replica running on its own machine, receiving messages from the web and pushing them into Kafka (6/7)
- I want 3 MyConsumer replicas all running in the last machine (7/7), which pull from Kafka and insert in Cassandra.

With docker swarm I used to handle container distribution with node labels, e.g. I would label three machines and Cassandra container configuration as C_HOST, 2 machines and Kafka configuration as K_HOST,... The swarm deployment would place each container correctly.

I have the following questions:

- Does Kubernetes pods bring any advantage comparing to my previous approach (e.g. simplicity)? I understood that I am still required to configure labels, if so, I don't see the appeal.
- What would be the correct way to configure these pods? Would it be one pod for Cassandra replicas, one pod for Kafka replicas, one pod for MyConsumer replicas and one pod for MyProducer?

Comment: are you mixing up pods and nodes? in kubernetes a *node* would be one of your clustered powerful machines, a *pod* is simply a wrapper around a container (possibly several containers, but that's typically only for sidecars). so in other words your pods are replicas, configured by a *deployment*. you can set a node affinity to pods. i fail to see why every service should run on a dedicated node in a cluster though as opposed to simply run it on a dedicated unclustered machine.

Comment: Thanks Markus, I’m not mixing the concepts I understand that a node is a machine.

Comment: This is just an example, my deployments include containers that need to run on dedicated machines and containers that don’t. I want this example to also have both cases, so that I better understand how to play with pods

Comment: @João Matos in kubernetes you have node labels too and you can use nodeselector with your deployments

Comment: In case if you want deep dive into `NodeAffinity`. https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-affinities/

Answer (score 3):

Using pod anti-affinity, you can ensure that a pod is not co-located with other pods with specific labels.

So say your have a label "app" with values "cassandra", "kafka", "my-producer" and "my-consumer".

Since you want to have cassandra, kafka and my-producer on dedicated nodes all by themselves, you simply configure an anti-affinity to ALL the existing labels:

(see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/ for full schema)

```
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - labelSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: app
        operator: In
        values:
        - cassandra
        - kafka
        - my-producer
        - my-consumer
```

This is for a "Pod" resource, so you'd define this in a deployment (where you also define how many replicas) in the pod template.

Since you want three instances of my-consumer running on the same node (or really, you don't care where they run, since by now only one node is left), you do not need to define anything about affinity or anti-affinity:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-consumer
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: my-consumer
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-consumer
  replicas: 3 # here you set the number of replicas that should run
  template:   # this is the pod template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-consumer # now this is the label you can set an anti-affinity to
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ${IMAGE}
        name: my-consumer
#       affinity:
# now here below this you'd put the affinity-settings from above
# for the other deployments
```

Comment: thanks Markus, do I still need to label each node as in @ozlevka answer? I.e. running the command kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value> at each node?

Comment: you only need to do that if you want to pin a pod to a specific node. typically the scheduler decides on what node a pod is started. depending on your setup it may be difficult to ensure node labels (for example if you are on a managed cluster).

Comment: Yes, so this means that the only advantage in having pods over "my old way of doing things" is that in *some particular cases* it may be useful to have a single pod yielding multiple containers that share resources (e.g. volumes, network, etc..)? Hence there is no relevant advantage in having a single pod with a single container VS having a single docker container? In line with this, if the three cassandra machines each has a volume, it does not make sense to have the three cassandra replicas in the same pod?

Comment: in kubernetes a pod is the only thing you can run, so it's not really about advantages. having replicas in a pod does not make sense, no, a pod is replicated itself, not the container(s) inside it.
multiple containers in a pod are typically only used for things like sidecar proxies for logging or service mesh networking.
it does not make sense to have three cassandra replicas in the same pod, it makes sense to have three replicas in the cluster and the master may schedule them on the same node if not configured differently, which may make sense in a scale out situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use node labels and use [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) parameter.

> You can add node labels by using kubectl...
>
> `kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>` to add a label to the node you’ve chosen.

But more advanced way is use [affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) for pod distribution...