# Running one pod per node with deterministic hostnames

Tags: kubernetes

I have what I believe is a simple goal, but I can't figure out how to get Kubernetes to play ball.

For my particular application, I am trying to deploy a number of replicas of a docker image that is a worker for another service. This system uses the hostname of the worker to distinguish between workers that are running at the same time.

I would like to be able to deploy a cluster where every node runs a worker for this service.

The problem is that the master also keeps track of every worker that ever worked for it, and displays these in a status dashboard. The intent is that you spin up a fixed number of workers by hand and leave it that way. I would like to be able to resize my cluster and have the number of workers change accordingly.

This seems like a perfect application for DaemonSet, except that then the hostnames are randomly generated and the master ends up tracking many orphaned hostnames.

An alternative might be StatefulSet, which gives us deterministic hostnames, but I can't find a way to force it to scale to one pod per node.

The system I am running is open source and I am looking into changing how it identifies workers to avoid this mess, but I was wondering if there was any sensible way to dynamically scale a StatefulSet to the number of nodes in the cluster. Or any way to achieve similar functionality.

Comment: Based on my experience, I can guess. DaemonSet - for ideal work with any service components, if your application requires work in DaemonSet logics - you have a problem. The idea of kubernetes is that you don’t have to think where your application is running so that the applications come together in a cluster - you need to use third-party things to do this (external consul or AKKA cluster like).

Comment: you can distribute the pods among nodes by defining anti-affinity. setting anti-affinity will ensure that kubernetes does not schedule two pods with the same label to the same node. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944755/kubernetes-pod-distribution/54945280#54945280

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already seen affinities, but perhaps I misunderstood them. How do they interact with the number of replicas? The intent is to make sure that exactly one replica is assigned to each node to avoid resource conflicts. I thought that if I had more replicas than nodes it would just schedule them on the same node anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The one way is to use [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector),  but I totally agree with @Markus: the more correct and advanced way is to use  [anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity). This is really powerful and at the same time simple solution to prevent scheduling pods with the same labels to 1 node.